# About Erlang http proxy

Tags: http, proxy, erlang

Is there some Erlang http proxy?
Which is the best Erlang http client? 
httpc seems lake of document, for example, How to send the cookie header in httpc?
Any example of Erlang http proxy, or proxy in mochiweb?

Comment: This is a test of the comment system. Ignore this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once built a proxy that did something like [upside-down-ternet](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) with a combination of [webmachine](http://webmachine.basho.com) and imagemagick. It was based on [this](https://bitbucket.org/bryan/wmexamples/src/tip/src/couchdb_proxy.erl) resource example.

I concur with Alexander that [lhttpc](https://github.com/oscarh/lhttpc) and [ibrowse](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse) are the best http clients. I've used both in production with great success.

Answer (score 2):

I can not recall name of any relatively famous http proxy written in erlang. Quick google search reveals this: http://www.duomark.com/erlang/tutorials/proxy.html

As for http client, I would recommend to try [lhttpc](https://bitbucket.org/etc/lhttpc/wiki/Home) or ibrowse

If an http client does not have a built-in method to specify a cookie in a request, usually you can construct an http Cookie header and pass it to the http requests handler function as a part of the request http headers.

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP proxy implemented in Erlang is now available on GitHub:  https://github.com/Wavenet/http_proxy

Answer (score 1):

I understand this question has been answered but i`m going to leave this here, just in case someone is looking for something simple, straight forward and readable.

```
-module(proxy).
-define(HTTP_PORT, 80).
-define(DEFAULT_PROXY_PORT, 8000).
-export([start/0,start/1,worker/1]).


start()->
    start (?DEFAULT_PROXY_PORT).

start(Port)->
    {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen (Port, [binary,
                  {packet, 0},
                  {reuseaddr, true},
                  {active, false},
                  {delay_send, false},
                  {nodelay, true}]),

    server_loop (Listen).

server_loop (Listen)->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept (Listen),
    spawn (?MODULE, worker, [Socket]),
    server_loop (Listen).

worker (Socket)->
    {ok, Request} = gen_tcp:recv (Socket, 0),
    ListRequest = binary_to_list (Request),
    io:format ("~p ~n", [ListRequest]),
    [Head, URL | RequestTail] = string:tokens (ListRequest, " "),
    ["http:", Host | URLTail] = string:tokens (URL, "/"),
    Document = "/" ++ string:join (URLTail, "/"),
    NewRequest = string:join ([Head, Document | RequestTail], " "),
    io:format ("~p ~p ~p~n", [self(), Host, Document]),
    {ok, SecondSocket} = gen_tcp:connect (Host, ?HTTP_PORT, [binary,
                             {packet, 0},
                             {active, false},
                             {delay_send, false},
                             {nodelay, true}]),
    ok = gen_tcp:send (SecondSocket, NewRequest),
    io:format ("~p waiting...~n", [self()]),
    Response = read_tcp (SecondSocket),
    io:format ("~p done!~n", [self()]),
    ok = gen_tcp:send (Socket, Response),
    gen_tcp:close (SecondSocket),
    gen_tcp:close (Socket).

read_tcp (Socket)->
    read_tcp (Socket, []).

read_tcp (Socket, SoFar)->
    case gen_tcp:recv (Socket, 0, 500) of
     {ok, Response} ->
         read_tcp (Socket, [Response | SoFar]);
     {error, timeout} ->
         lists:reverse (SoFar);
     {error, closed} ->
         lists:reverse (SoFar)
    end.
```